# Can we use AutoEncoder for Sparse Sensing?

Tags: compressive-sensing, deep-learning

Is there a way to introduce sparsity constraint on an autoencoder to achieve compressions in the Cosine/Fourier domain? I want to use the encoder part of the Auto encoder as the feature extractor from the STL-10 dataset.
https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/autoencoders
The features learned should be more optimized than the compression algorithms like JPEG.

Comment: you're stating a conflicting demand: you want your encoder to produce sparse data, but you want that data to be highly compressed. That is in conflict; or did I misunderstand what is supposed to be sparse in your model?

Comment: I want the encoder to highly compress the data like in the JPEG and then using the data to decode back the original image. The weights learn should be similar to the DFT basis.

Comment: yeah. so, that's what you basically always do when designing an autoencoder, you've got data->encoder->penalty->decoder, where "penalty" is typically a low-dimensional vector, and potentially a function applied to that. That's the most classical autoencoder thing I can think of!

Comment: Ya. That is exactly what I want to do. I am trying to replicate the compressions with some learned basis like DFT/others. Do you have any good idea on enforcing the weights of the encoder to some good basis?

Comment: Do the machine learning thing and initialize them randomly. If that doesn't work, you can put expert knowledge in it.

Comment: @Yvon, Could you please review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When we train Auto Encoder we usually apply the loss function on the result obtained from the decoder and not the encoder.
Hence the obvious step, adding a sparsity promoting regularization to the loss function, won't do what we're after.

What you may do is adding to the loss function the $ {L}_{1} $ norm, or any other differential regularization which fits you model (Maybe the KL Divergence), based on the output of the *encoder*.

Adding this penalty will promote sparsity at the **output of the encoder**.

Comment: Have you ever implemented something like that?

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to do. If you have separate backbones for the encoder and decoder, all needed is to hook the encoder output to the loss.